# JS execute function only when near bottom and not on every window scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, scroll

Got this working code snippet from somewhere on the web but i cannot figure out how to modify it. the problem is : it executes the function EVERY TIME i scroll, no matter where on the page.

it should only execute when im near the bottom though.

it is a snippet for "infinite scroll"

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$(window).scroll(fetchPosts);

function fetchPosts() {

    var page = $('.endless-pagination').data('next-page');

    if(page !== null) {

        clearTimeout( $.data( this, "scrollCheck" ) );

        $.data( this, "scrollCheck", setTimeout(function() {
            var scroll_position_for_posts_load = $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop() + 100;

            if(scroll_position_for_posts_load >= $(document).height()) {
                $.get(page, function(data){
                    $('.posts').append(data.posts);
                    $('.endless-pagination').data('next-page', data.next_page);
                });
            }
        }, 350))

    }
}
```

})

any ideas my fellow programmers?
Using Laravel 5.2

Answer (score 0):

working Solution:

```
 window.onscroll = function() {
     if ((window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset) >= (document.body.scrollHeight - 500)) {
         fetchPosts();
     }
 };
```

-500 to exec the function a little before the bottom has been reached.